# Git workflow for new developer onboard

Tags: git, git-workflow

We've a new junior developer to join the team and want to contribute to a project. The issue is, we expect a lot of garbage commits due to the lack of experience and we need to do code-review on every commit at the beginning.

What would be a suitable git workflow in this case? 
We don't want his garbage history to pollute our master branch.

Comment: What workflow do you currently use for your other developers?  How do you code review everyone else?  You aren't all just committing to master are you?

Comment: In short: everyone commits to a branch and creates Pull requests to merge to master. The process for new developers is "do the same as everyone else".

Comment: Use something like gerrit, or emulate its workflow.  

In his repo: If branch origin/take80 exists, then a local take80 should not exist, but instead like:  take80_bug01234 that rebases origin/take80.  Make sure that all pulls are --rebase (no merge commits).  And before pushing up take80_bug01234 for review, make him "git rebase -i".  Let him know that only fast-forward merges (ie: rebase before push) will even be considered, and that the thing being reviewed should be one commit so it can be approved or rejected as a unit.

Comment: Note that from the perspective of an integrator looking at the central bare repo, if you do branch -r and see:  take79, take80, take80_bug01234, take80_bug12345 ... you can interpret that as two pull requests for take80.  As the integrator, you can ff merge it into take80, or delete the branch in order to reject it.  It's too bad that pull requests can't be pushed up into remote branches more explicitly (going through some other medium instead), so comments should give sufficient information to function as a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

Have him commit to a different branch and check his work before merging to master.